# How to allow selection of multiple rows + enable de-selection of rows in dynamically-created table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new to programming and website development, so apologies for the noobish question and sloppy code. I've searched online for answers, but these solutions apply to static tables, not a dynamically-created one like mine.

I've already got the table formatted so that, when you click on a row, that row is selected and its BG color changes. I also already have it configured so that when the user clicks the "Get selected rows" button after clicking on a row, the [Description] of the selected row will be sent to the future PHP webpage.

I'm nearly happy, except that I would also like to implement these 2 features:

- If the user left-clicks on a second/third/etc unselected row, then **multiple** row selections can be made and un-made. (I want the [Descriptions] of ALL highlighted rows to be sent when the user clicks the "Get selected rows"  button.)
- If the user left-clicks on an already-selected row, then that row becomes de-selected. (This means that the row's BG color returns to its original color and the row [Description] will no longer be sent by the "Get selected rows" button).

[My full HTML code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/integral/Lbv0gbsu).

For the section of JavaScript code that relates to my question, search for the following line: `window.onload = function () {`

For the bit of CSS code that changes the BG color of the row on click, search for:  `tr.selected`

I've spent 20 hours trying to bring these 2 features to life but the complexity of the code has really made this difficult. If anyone can help I would so appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look at your code and I modify it as you need.
Hope this is what you expected.
First, change `highlight` function to make multiple select is possible.

```
function highlight(e) {
    if (e.target.parentNode.className != ''){
        //if already selected, then unselect
        e.target.parentNode.className = '';
    }else{
        //if not selected then select it
        e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';
    }
}
```

After that, you need to modify the click event for OK button as follow.

```
$("#tst").click(function () {
        var value = "";

        //get all selected row
        var selected = $(".selected");
        //loop through all selected row and get all first column value
        for(var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++){
            if(value != "") value = value + ", ";
            value = value + selected[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
        }

        value = value || "No row Selected";
        alert(value);
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This is exactly what I want! You are a complete life saver, Viki!